# If normally distributed random vector $X$ has a PD covariance matrix, then any conditional distribution induced by $X$ has a PD covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, linear-algebra, multivariate-distribution

Suppose I have a random vector $X$ whose distribution is joint normal. I know that the covariance matrix of $X$ is positive definite. I wonder if I partition $X$ in any way: e.g., $X=(X_1, X_2)$, then the conditional distribution of $X_1\mid X_2$ has a positive definite covariance matrix.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I know that under this condition $X_1 | X_2$ is normal with the $Cov(X1|X2) = \Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \Sigma_{21}$, where $\Sigma_{ij}$ is the $i,j$ block of the covariance matrix of $(X_1, X_2)$. You may already know this but just in case this helps...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3423431/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2619070/321264, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness